# How do I download a local database from a WP8 device?

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, local-database

I have an application in the WP8 marketplace which uses a local database.  I'm having an issue with this application and I think it's because there is an error in the DB upgrade mechanism.

I'd like to download the local database from my WP8 device (it's a developer device) and then upload it onto an emulator so I can test the upgrade processes.

Things I've already tried:

ISETool - doesn't allow me to look at applications downloaded from the store
IsoStoreSpy - same issue as above

I've not tried Windows Phone Power Tools as this is for uploading and downloading dev packages.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can't access IsolatedStorage from an application downloaded from the store. Only for "dev app".

Comment: So maybe the best idea is to run dev app and make method to save db on IS and then send it to PC by e-mail composer?